# Change datatable and tableadapter schema at runtime according to stored procedure. C#

Tags: sql-server, datatable, tableadapter

I have DataSet and TableAdapter for the table in that DataSet. The problem is that TableAdapter uses a stored procedure to fill DataTable, but the amount of returned columns can be different.
How can I change the schema of DataTable at runtime to get all the columns from stored procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, drop the idea of using the DataAdapter, it's completely unnecessary. Do this to get the DataTable instead:

```
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Conectionstring"))
{
    con.Open();
    using (SqlCommand commnand= new SqlCommand("StoredProcName",con))
    {
             command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
             DataTable table = new DataTable();
             table.Load(reader);
             return table;
    }
}
```

Now it doesn't matter the # of columns you return from the proc, the datatable will contain all of them.

EDIT: Add the following section to your Web.config file below the `<configuration>` section replacing the actual connectionString for yours. You should be able to copy this from the Your Settings file.

And now create your SqlConnection as follows:

```
SqlConnection con 
= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
```

Notice that "ConnectionString" is the name attribute of the connection string in the Web.Config.

See another [example here,](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2005/12/28/ASPNET-20-How-to-get-a-specific-ConnectionString-from-the-WebConfig-by-name.aspx) in case is not very clear.

Comment: This decision is good for me, thanks. But now I have trouble with connection.Open(). I use connectionString from Properties.Settings.Default.myConnectionString and when I try to open connection I get error:26 form sql server =( Dont know how to resolve this. TableAdapters using that connectionString work fine...